# How to add radiobutton and combobox selections into a listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

### Heading

I have a form that has radiobutton A, B, C and a comboBox with numbers 0, 1, 3.
What I am attempting to do is create List of characters for each selected radiobutton and a  List of integers for each selected item in comboBox. Then, I want them to load it into a created listBox.

This is a portion of my code:

```
if (!(radA.Checked || radB.Checked || radC.Checked || radD.Checked || radF.Checked)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("A grade must be selected."); 
} 
else if (radA.Checked) 
{ //add the checked radiobutton into List<int> letGrade 
    allGrades.Add('A'); 
}
```

I'm also implementing the same approach in the comboBox:

```
     if (cboCreditHrs.SelectedIndex == -1)//if" no credit is selected
      {
                    MessageBox.Show("Credit hours must be selected.");
                }
                else if (cboCreditHrs.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    allHours.Add(0);
                }
                else if (cboCreditHrs.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    allHours.Add(1);
                }
```

I have not created the the other List<>. However, my desire is to load all the List<> items of each list into the listBox and I'm uncertain as to how to implement this?

The result in the ListBox should display:

A - 1 - A1, where A1 is the sum of A &1.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? Please [edit] the question and tag it accordingly.

Comment: Winforms, WPF? It's a *lot* easier to do so with WPF than it is with Winforms

Comment: @Pinkfit, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @Panagiotis, I forgot to mention that I'm developing this in Windows forms applications.

Answer (score 0):

The CheckedListBox control gives you all the capability of a list box and also allows you to display a check mark next to the items in the list box.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Sunday", CheckState.Checked);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Monday", CheckState.Unchecked);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Tuesday", CheckState.Indeterminate);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Wednesday", CheckState.Checked);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Thursday", CheckState.Unchecked);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Friday", CheckState.Indeterminate);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Saturday", CheckState.Indeterminate);
}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want a check mark displayed into the listbox. All I want is to display the selected values in the listbox. So for instance, I selected A in the radio buttons group, 1 in the combo box, and the sum of the two selection,   it will be displayed as such in the listbox:           A, 1, A1